# Do an external redirect seems not working on a test ( sf4 / phpunit )

Tags: phpunit, symfony4

I would like to test a redirect to an external url making by a controller.

It works fine when I execute my app by myself but when I execute a functional test on this controller, I've got:

```
"Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found ....  (from "http://localhost/")"
```

I use:

`$this->redirect('http://.../.../...')`

in my controller.

Coud you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony crawler that is used to mock a web browser during functional tests does not actually make any HTTP request. In fact, it can't.
That's why it cannot test external URLs.